# Find out if another user has read write permissions

Tags: c#, sqlite, permissions

I have an application that uses an Sqlite database

This database must be located somewhere that a non-admin has read/write access to

It will invariably be an administrator that installs the software for all users, but they persist in trying to install the app into Program Files which does not have write access to a non admin. thus the normal user cant use the app.

I need to check in the installer that the selected folder has read/write permissions for non admins, but I cant seem to find any help that isnt only about the "Current" user.

so

**How can I find out whether or not non-admins have read write access to a folder?**

- C#
- Sqlite 3
- Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Locate database file in all users appdata folder.

Comment: unfortunately I have some other dlls that require the database to be in the same directory as the executable, hence my problem

Comment: I don't get it. You must provide path to file. If it's not your component you must have ability to pass path.